# how to arpspoof when the AP prevent clients from seeing each others?

Tags: network, arp-spoofing

I am trying to perform man-in-the-middle attack on my home network.I can fool the AP into thinking that I am the client by this command

```
arpspoof -i wlan0 -t 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.10
```

however when I try to make the client think that I am the AP

```
arpspoof -i wlan0 -t 192.168.1.10 192.168.1.1
```

The client keep sending the packets to AP.
I know this because when I open wireshark I can see the packets going to the clients only.I cannot see any packets coming from the client.
I went through the router settings but there's nothing seem to be related to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Except for very specific cases ([TDLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TDLS)) all traffic between clients will go through the access point. So arp spoofing will never make a client send data directly to you.

Comment: What I mean is that there is something in this network preventing my ARP packet to reach to the victim.When I open wireshark in the victim computer I cannot see any arp packet coming from the attacker machine.